# Почему не работает удаление файлов через makefile

Tags: windows, makefile

Есть папка. В ней лежит `makefile` и еще пару папок с файлами:

[image: директория]

Допустим, что в папке `third_pracice` есть файл `a.txt`, который мне надо удалить через `makefile`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `makefile` я написал такую цель:

```
clean:
    rm ./third_pracice/a.txt
```

Когда я запускаю `make`, то он выдает ошибку:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\cashr\Desktop\pracice\cmp> make clean
> rm ./third_pracice/a.txt
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm ./third_pracice/a.txt, ...) failed.
> make (e=2): Ia oaaaony iaeoe oeacaiiue oaee.
> makefile:2: recipe for target 'clean' failed
> make: *** [clean] Error 2
> ```

В чем проблема? Если закинуть эту команду напрямую в терминал, то проблем нет. Пробовал использовать указание "sudo", не помогло. Как работает удаление из других папок через `make`?

ОС - Windows

Comment: Добавьте метку используемой ОС.

Comment: Наверное, стоит начать с вопроса — а существует ли у вас команда `rm` вообще?

Comment: Откуда вы установили мейк?

Comment: 1)ОС - windows
2)команда rm существует (опять же, как я писал, если ввести команду из мейкфайла в терминал - все работает). Плюс к этому я могу через makefile удалить файл который лежит в той же папке, что и мейкфайл, но когда пытаюсь удалить из другой папки - вылезает ошибка.
3) устанавливал с оффициального сайта cmake

сам makefile работает на ура, то есть свой функционал он выполняет, скомпилировать файл из других папок тоже могу. И вот единственная проблема - это удаление файлов из другой папки и с чем она связана я ума не приложу...

Comment: «если ввести команду из мейкфайла в терминал» — в тот же самый терминал, в котором запускается make?

Comment: *"устанавливал с оффициального сайта cmake"* Я спросил про Make, не про CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код

```
clean:
    rm ./third_pracice/a.txt
```

измените на

```
clean:
    del .\third_pracice\a.txt
```

потому что команде `rm` (POSIX) соответствует команда `del` (Windows) и слеши (`/`) обратная слеш (`\`).

Comment: Однако это не объясняет утверждение «Если закинуть эту команду напрямую в терминал, то проблем нет.»

Comment: @andreymal, не надо всему верить — *«доверяй каждому, не верь ничему»*.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы `del` не использовал. Нужно стремиться к кросс-платформенным мейкфайлам, а `del` - чисто виндовая вещь.

Если у вас не работает `rm`, значит вы либо скачали не тот Make, либо как-то странно его запускаете.

Снесите ваш Make. Поставьте [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/2752075). Там запустите `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-make`, чтобы установить их версию Make, и потом запускайте `mingw32-make` из консоли MSYS2 (ярлык `MSYS2 UCRT64` в меню пуск). (Есть еще просто `make`, который ставится из `pacman -S make` - он тормозит сильнее, и для вашего случая никакой другой разницы нет.)

Answer (score 0):

В терминале у вас запущен интерпретатор команд `powershell`. В нем `rm` является алиасом для командлета `Remove-Item`. Утилита `make` не является интерпретатором команд и не использует `powershell`, для выполнения каждой директивы она тупо запускает дочерний процесс. Соответственно чтобы `rm` работало в `make` необходимо, чтобы в `PATH` присутствовал исполняемый файл `rm` (`rm.exe`), который обычно распространяется как часть `posix coreutils` или их суррогатов. Так что если собираетесь использовать `rm`, то `make` необходимо запускать из окружения, где они уже установлены, например из ранееупомянутого `msys` или из `git bash`.